# How to only print out lines from a file that match a certain set of conditions?

Tags: java, eclipse, list, text

I need to import a file and have a scanner only print out the movies in the list.  The movies are always the first words in the line and are always formatted such that they will appear as the title and then the year in parentheses:

> Saving Private Ryan (1998)

Following the movie title there will be a / and then an actors name formatted like last name, first name and then another slash and then the next actors name. When the actors for the movie have all been listed the line ends and the same thing occurs for another movie on the next line.

How can I make a code that will list all of the movies with a certain actor in them, list all of the actors for a certain movie, list all the movies (without the actors), list all the movies released in a certain year and so on?

Comment: What have you tried? What issues have you encountered and need help on? Or are you just looking for somebody to do your homework for you?

Comment: I'd parse the file into a `Map<Movie, List<Actor>>`.  There are tons of tools in Java that allow you to manipulate collections however you like.

Comment: I'm not looking for anyone to do my homework I'm just looking for a nod in the right direction.  I would make an arraylist of movies by using .matches(regex) to only add the ones that match the format of "words" (numbers) but when I ask it to print out all the ones that have those conditions, nothing prints out and I suspect it's because its only looking at individual words.  I don't know how to get it to look through an entire line and only pick out the part that is a movie title and then numbers in parentheses.

Comment: @JesseWiatrak Well then you should have put that in your original question along with some bits of code that are giving you trouble. Otherwise your question really looks like you're just looking for a shortcut instead of doing at least some of the work yourself, which is now clear that  you did, but wasn't obvious originally.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
    ArrayList<String> allMovies = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (String movie : allMovies)
    {
        if (movie.contains("Tom Hanks"))
            System.out.println(movie);
    }
```

or if you wanted to get more specific you could separate each of your movies into their different categories (title, actor, year) by using [split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

```
String[] arr = movie.split("/");
```

Edit:

Sorry, I thought you had your movies in a List, but the idea is still the same.  You want to iterate through each movie in your scanner and if it contains the matching phrase you want print it out.  Something Like this:

```
while (scanner.hasNext())
{
    String movie = scanner.next();
    //split the movie by "/"
    String[] arr = movie.split("/");
    //if movie contains phrase, print it out
    if (movie.contains("Tom Hanks"))
    {
        //print out title
        System.out.println(arr[0]);
    }
}
```

or like I mentioned before you can split the movie up by the forward slash

Comment: Be aware I'm a beginner, so I tried running that code and it did nothing.  I put it in the scanner.

Comment: How  would I incorporate the split thing.  I already have a class firstName that prints theScanner.next() so how could I make firstName.split("/") work?

Comment: Drop27 that works great but since I have to make it scanner.nextLine().contains("Tom Hanks"), it prints out the entire line including the actors.  How can I make it so it only prints out the first words of each line until it reaches an open parentheses?

Comment: I think I've given you good enough head start you might want to check out the substring and indexOf methods for String

Comment: That is incredibly helpful.  Thank you.

Comment: One more problem.  I got it to work by doing the last code you posted, but I need to be able to make it a string and return what is displayed in the console as a string, and whenever I place this within a string rather than public static void main.  However when I place the entire scanner inside a string with the constructor (firstname, lastname) and try to create the string from another class's void main, it tells me it needs to be static, and changing the string to static just screws it up.

Comment: It'd probably be a good idea to open a new question for that, and post your code along with your error.